# Snubber Filter Circuit Not Working Triac Dimmer

Tags: components, triac, phase, dimmer, snubber

Hi I am working on a project using a triac to do phase control dimming of 120V ac powered devices. I recently translated my project from perfboard to SMT using an SMT fabrication service. The project appears to be working correctly, except for the snubber filter section. Despite having a snubber filter, I can see on my scope that the ac output still has a hard cut-in in the middle of the waveform and I can hear an audible buzzing from the board at dimmer settings where the ac waveform turns on mid cycle. I am testing with a 43W incandescent bulb.

I have checked that the components are the correct value and were installed correctly. Is there anything in component selection that might cause this? Here is the relevant schematic section showing the triac and the snubber filter:

[image: Triac + Snubber Schematic]

Here are the components I picked for Q1, R13, and C6 respectively:

[image: Q1 Triac]
[image: R13 Snubber Resistor]
[image: C6 Snubber Cap]

Comment: Describe how your 2f phase control is done with PWM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R13 and C6 are not really suitable for mains operation. C6 should be X2 rated. The capacitor for C6 you're currently using is piezo electric, so it is most likely causing the buzz you hear. R13 isn't surge rated.

If you want to slow the edge, you need an inductor in series with the load like all good phase control light dimmers have. R6/C13 is only for snubbing the triac.

Comment: Okay thank you, I thought it might be something to do with component selection. What does the X2 rating provide that is necessary for the snubber circuit? Hadn't found that in my reading online.

Comment: Did you google capacitor x2 ?

Comment: understood... would these components work as better options? https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/CRGP2512F100R/A130709CT-ND/8578541?itemSeq=388588400

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/BFC233820104/BC1601-ND/502381?itemSeq=388589679

Comment: Or perhaps this for an SMD version of the capacitor?

Comment: Replacing the ceramic with a film cap I had in stock fixed the buzzing issue. For the resistor am I correct in understanding that that's mainly a safety thing to prevent damage in the case of external surge conditions. Under normal operating conditions the resistor doesn't get hot and the snubber now works as intended. I also fuse the AC power input to the circuit at 8A if that's a relevant consideration

Answer (score 2):

Snubbers act like a pressure relief valve around the switch and slow the resulting dI/dT for inductive loads which reduces the peak voltage. The problem is you an incandescent light is not inductive load so your snubber won't really slow anything at all.

Comment: I am measuring the voltage at J5 pin 2. This is a digitally controlled dimmer, so it provides phase control by turning on the triac at an early or later point in the waveform. Perhaps 'cuts in' would have been more accurate.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima Understood. So you're seeing ringing or something when it cuts in?

Comment: I now understand that the waveform looked normal for a non-inductive device, but I was concerned with the fact the I was hearing a buzzing noise from the PCB. After replacing the SMT ceramic cap with a bigger film capacitor I no longer have that issue.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima So what was the buzzing? Was it just the piezo behaviour of the ceramic cap acting as a speaker and not actually a problem with the cap functioning? Or something else? EDIT: Oh, I see the other answer did say it might have just been piezo behaviour.